# hidden increment of variable occurres

Tags: javascript, variables, loops, scope

Basic question here.. second `console.log(k);` prints out 10 and not 9, why is that ?

```
function test (o) {
  var i = 0;
  if(typeof o == "object") {
      var j = 0;
      for(var k=0;k<10;k++){
          console.log(k);
      }
      console.log(k);
  }
  console.log(j);
}

test(o);
```

Comment: `10` is printed because JavaScript doesn't have block scope and when `k < 10` fails, `k` is `10`.

Comment: @Juhana sry i didn't read carefully

Comment: @Blender: `k` is not set to some other value or shadowed, I don't see how JavaScript's lack of block scope changes anything.

Comment: k get increment before print the log(k) so use while loop it will work for u

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: You're referencing it outside of the loop. Similar code doesn't work in C++, which does have block scope.

Comment: @Blender: yes, but the OP expects it to be 9 (not an error), which implies that the OP is aware of that fact.

Comment: If `k` were 9, then the second `console.log` statement wouldn't get executed, because `k<10` would still be true

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: in C++, such a loop _could_ do this: `for(int k=0;k<10;++k) ::k = k;`... that's only possible owing to block-scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer would be: if you'd expect `k` to be 9, then you can't expect the `for` loop to be over at the same time, because `if (k === 9) console.log(k<10);` will log ***true***, hence your second `console.log(k)` wouldn't get executed.
That's it. Now the long answer:

Well, basically, a `for` loop consists of 3 distinct statements:

```
for (var k=0;k<10;k++)
```

You need to understand when JS will execute each statement. In the first case, it's pretty simple:

```
k=0
```

The assignment gets executed when JS enters the loop, then (*before* executing the loop) the condition will be evaluated:

```
k<10 // == 0 < 10 == true
```

The loop body is executed, then *before* evaluating the conditional, the third statement is executed:

```
k++//increment k, k is 1 now
```

All well and good, now, assume

```
for(k=9;k<10;k++)
```

and apply the same logic. The loop body will be executed once, `k` is incremented, and now holds 10 as value. The condition evaluates to false, and JS will loop no longer.
Because JS isn't truly block-scoped, `k` will happily sit in memory until it's needed again, and because you didn't reassign it, it'll still hold `10` as value.

It really is *that* simple. It's actually like that most languages I know of...

Answer (score 0):

The loop doesn't stop till "k < 10" condition fails. At this point "k++" has already run and in this case k equals 10. That means that when the loop ends, k is going to still be 10 which is what prints!

Of course, the inside of the loop is only run when the condition succeeds which is why it is going to stop at "9".

**Side Note**

By the way, the reason this whole statement works in the first place is because javascript doesn't strongly enforce variable scopes the way other languages do. In other words, in many languages, if you declare a variable in a loop, aren't allowed to use that variable outside of the loop (at least if the variable is a primitive type).

I realize the question may have been entirely academic, but in general, my policy is to declare variables with the "var" keyword in javascript to ensure I'm not overwriting global variables and I also try to avoid situations like this one by observing "C" heritage scope rules. In other words, although this is an interesting question - its a coding practice that probably should be avoided. Hope that provides some guidance for others in the future!

Comment: pedantic note: `for(k=9;k<10;k++) k +=101;`. In that case, `k` won't ***equal*** 10, but the loop will still exit. In that sense, your answer is incorrect, or incomplete

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You are correct. Will update wording accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

At this line

```
for(var k=0;k<10;k++){
  console.log(k);
}
```

`k` has been incremented by `k++` incrementer. At last iteration, `k = 10` then condition fails and next `console.log(k)` print value of `k` as `10`.

Answer (score 0):

- "for" loop is valid as long as k<10 which means if k=9 console should prints out 9
- at the end of loop } it has to increment k based on k++ which means k=k+1 which makes k=10
- based on your k<10 rule it has to leave the loop and because of the second console log request, console should prints out 10